# Linear algebra word problem regarding ships

Tags: calculus

I have been provided with the answer to this question by my teacher but have no clue how to do the working out could someone please show me how you do the working out for this question?

Answer is: 74 miles

A and B are two ports 466 miles apart. ship X leaves A for B steaming at 8 knots. two hours later, ship Y leaves port A steaming at 20 knots. upon arriving at port B, ship Y does a 20 hour turnaround and then steams back towards port A along the same track at the same speed

How far from port B will the two ships meet during  Y's return voyage

Answer is: 74 miles

Comment: By the way, this is not calculus, and although it is a linear problem, it is not what most people call linear algebra.  I would tag it as a word problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the "miles" refered to in the problem are nautical miles, so we don't have to convert between knots and miles per hour.

Position of $X$ at time $t$ is $X = 8t$.

Position of $Y$ until it reaches port $B$ is $B = 20 (t-2)$, becauwe it leaves at $t=2$.

$Y$ reaches port $B$ when $20 (t-2) = 466$ or $t = 2+\frac{466}{20} = \frac{253}{10}$.

Y leaves port $B$ at $t = 20 + \frac{253}{10} = \frac{453}{10}$.

Position of $Y$ on its way back is 
$$
Y = 466 - 20(t - \frac{453}{10}) = 1372 - 20 t
$$
We now solve 
$$
8t = 1372 - 20 t $$
giving 
$$
t = \frac{1372}{28} = 49
$$
Finally, to find the distance from port $A$ of the meeting, we note that ship $X$ has sailed 
$$
8 \cdot 49 = 392 $$

and remains $466-392 = 74$ miles away from port $B$.